# How to monitor a function for changes in Angular / breeze?

Tags: angularjs, breeze, single-page-application

With the following code:

```
$scope.hasChanges = datacontext.manager.hasChanges;
```

I'm trying to give the view some insight into whether or not the current breeze context has any changes to enable/disable some buttons:

```
<button ng-disabled="!hasChanges" class="btn btn-warning cancel" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
```

This works if I set true/false in the view, but if I try to call hasChanges or haschanges(), the buttons are always disabled.

I also tried this:

```
 $scope.$watch(datacontext.manager.hasChanges, function () {
    $scope.hasChanges = datacontext.manager.hasChanges;
});
```

to no avail.

How can I tell the view when there are changes to the breeze hasChanges?  In knockout I would just use an observable... I wonder what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `$scope.hasChanges = datacontext.manager.hasChanges;` is classic JavaScript. You're watching a function (`hasChanges`) that has been torn away from its owning object (the `manager`).

Try this instead:

`$scope.isCancelDisabled = function () {return !datacontext.manager.hasChanges();};`

Then write your html like this:

```
<button ng-disabled="isCancelDisabled()" ... ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
```

Of course that will call `datacontext.manager.hasChanges()` frequently. It's pretty fast but you will be calling it roughly twice every digest cycle. If (and I mean "IF") you discover through measurement that this is too slow for your screen (again, I said "IF") ... you could turn `cancelDisabled` into a field of the VM and set it by listening to the `hasChangesChanged` event as Jay suggested. I'm not sure I'd bother.

Answer (score 2):

The Breeze EntityManager has a "hasChangesChanged" event that you can subscribe to.  Something like:

```
myEntityManager.hasChangesChanged.subscribe(function(args) {
    var hasChanges = args.hasChanges;
    var entityManager = args.entityManager;
    ... do something interesting...
});
```

The EntityManager also has an EntityChanged event that might be useful.

Also see: [EntityManager api docs](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html)

Comment: Thanks Jay.  I'm a bit at a loss (new to Breeze) - if you get the time, how would I pair this up with the angular code / view?